# Find the sum $a,b,c,d,e,f,g$

Tags: geometry

> Find the sum $$a,b,c,d,e,f,g.$$
>
> where $a,b,c,d,e,f,g$ are the angles shown in the figure
>
> [image]

It's beautiful problem, and it's for sharing a new answers, thanks:)

Answer (score 3):

[image: angles]

The red dots sum to $5\pi$, and so do the orange dots.

Each red/orange/green/green combo sums to $2\pi$, there are $7$ of them, so the green dots sum to $4\pi$.

Each triangle containing a named angle sums to $\pi$, in total $7\pi$.

So, subtracting the green dots, $a+b+c+d+e+f+g=7\pi-4\pi=3\pi$.

Answer (score 2):

The interior angles of the heptagon are $5\pi$.
The small exterior angles clockwise from each vertex add up to $2\pi$.
The small exterior angles anticlockwise from each vertex add up to $2\pi$.
Those exterior angles plus $a+b+c+d+e+f+g$ add up to $7\pi$, so $a+b+c+d+e+f+g=3\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

$3\pi$ ... going along the path you just sum angles at your turns, get $7(\pi-"angle")=7\pi -(a+b+ \ldots... +g)$, which has to be $4\pi$. Hence the result.

Comment: is this right? - $4\pi$ is 8 right-angles

Answer (score 0):

3$\pi$. Proof is as follows:

See the image: [image]
Consider quadrilateral made of vertices $A,C,N,F$. We have $a+c+n+f=2\pi$ or $a+c+f=2\pi-n$. Similarly, in quadrilateral by $B,M,E,G$, we have $b+e+g=2\pi-m$.

Now look at the triangle formed by the $M,N,D$. We see that $d=m+n-\pi$.

Adding the three equations we see $a+b+c+d+e+f+g=3\pi$.